using reflection to assign a dynamically created property
I am looking to assign a dynamically created property value but apparently I only get the value assigned to the backing field and not the actual property value when I call to propertyInfo.SetValue(instance, value);
here is there code:
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
 var dynamicAssemblyName = new AssemblyName("DynamicAssembly");
 AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(dynamicAssemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
 ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("DynamicModule");
 TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("DynamicType", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Sealed);

 foreach (var category in model.Categories)
 {
     var propertyName = category.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "_");
     var newPropType = typeof(string);

     PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, newPropType, null); //this property gets created
     MethodBuilder getMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod($"get_{propertyName}", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, newPropType, Type.EmptyTypes);
     MethodBuilder setMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod($"set_{propertyName}", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, null, new Type[] { newPropType });

     ILGenerator getIL = getMethod.GetILGenerator();
     getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
     getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, typeBuilder.DefineField($"_{propertyName}__BackingField_get", newPropType, FieldAttributes.Private));
     getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

     ILGenerator setIL = setMethod.GetILGenerator();
     setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // Load "this" onto the stack
     setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // Load the value onto the stack
     setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, typeBuilder.DefineField($"_{propertyName}__BackingField_set", newPropType, FieldAttributes.Private)); // Set the value at the backing field
     setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); // Return

     propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getMethod);
     propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setMethod);
 }

I tried passing the property builder with the actual property name at setIL.Emit but this doesnt seem to help, the current code only assigns to a backing field I don't the field but I only need the property to have an actual value assigned

It seems like you are using two different fields for storing and loading: $"_{propertyName}__BackingField_get, "_{propertyName}__BackingField_set". I think you should use the same field in both cases.

@thehennyy let me try that and will report back

for curiosity replaced " MethodBuilder getMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod($"get_{propertyName}", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, newPropType, Type.EmptyTypes);" Type.EmptyTypes with new {newPropType  }) and it didnt create the property itself

@thehennyy you are right I should use the same instance of define field for each of the emit calls

“...I only get the value assigned to the backing field and not the actual property...” Wrong statement. If your property has the explicit backing field, the assignment to this backing field is the assignment to the property. In other case you have to get the property getter (GetGetMethod) and invoke it with the desired new value.  It does not matter how you created the property. Does it solve your problem?
